# Making Server and Client program

Tags: server, client

I want to make some server and client type program but I don't know how to do that. I will describe it below:

It will have a GUI on windows and when I enter some text there and click send, it will first check if my mobile is connected with it or not (via Bluetooth or WiFi or cable anything), if it's connected it will send that message to an app or program in my phone. If my phone is not connected directly it will send that message via internet (assuming both my PC and mobile has active internet connection) to my particular mobile only. And this should be a two way communication.

I don't want to use any 3rd party APIs or software as long as possible.
Is such a thing possible? How can I achieve it? 
Or what should I learn to make such a thing?

Comment: Can you describe the purpose of the server-client project? That will help us give you a better answer. What programming language are you going to use and what is the most convenient way for the project to connect the mobile phone to the PC?

Comment: Purpose : I have developed a personal assistant using python that automates some of my task, tells me time, battery status etc. I can make same sort of thing for my mobile also using Android but I want a two-way communication between them. Like, If I am using my laptop and my phone is placed in the living room and is on silent. If I am getting a call then a program in my phone will check if it is connected to my laptop, if so it will send a message with the caller name to my laptop and my personal assistant here will read out the caller name for me.

Comment: Also if I want to send a text message to a person. I will command my personal assistant, it will send the message along with the name of the receiver to my phone and the program in my phone will then send the message accordingly.

Comment: I know Python, Android, MySQL for now and if some other language is required to implement this, I can learn that too. Coming to the type of connection between the mobile and PC, it depends. If I am at home, they will be connected through bluetooth or wifi. If the devices are far apart then the communication should take place via internet (assuming both devices have an active internet connection) and I don't want to use any 3rd party APIs and apps for the purpose (if it is possible without them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you don't need to learn another language to do this and you don't have to use external application and APIs. Your project benefits well from the master/slave architecture.

*The project will contain 3 systems*

- **Mobile:** This will the slave device. You want to intercept SMS and phone calls to forward that information to the computer. Along side that you also want to receive commands from the computer, ex: the computer commanding the phone to send an SMS to caller/contact. This requires an application that can listen to Android events for incoming calls and SMS. It is straight forward to do this with Android programming.
- **Computer:** You can make a GUI application that connects to an API and can send and receive data to mobile clients through the API. Python can do this job and you can connect to your personal assistant if it's also written in Python. This will be the master device.
- **Server API:** The computer and mobile will not communicate directly with each other. The server API will be a gateway for them to communicate, all you need is internet connection for both devices. This eliminates the need to use other type of connectivity such as Bluetooth and USB, and you don't need to have the devices in close proximity. It won't be an issue if it's a requirement to implement proximity. The API can be made with Python as a push API. You can immediately notify the computer once an incoming call is detected or when you want to send an SMS from the computer through the phone. An alternative to push APIs is a combination of REST API and TCP socket communication.

#### The benefits are:

- SMS and phone calls are received in real time
- No reliance on external applications and third party APIs
- You can stick to the programming languages you already know
- Easy scaling: you can add more phones

*Here are quick illustrations over how the systems can communicate:*

[image: System communication]

Once the data from the SMS/call is sent to the computer, you can forward the information and let the personal assistant handle it.

[image: Computer sends command]

There are multiple ways you can develop this project, this is one way you can to go at it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes I got the idea, you explained it very nicely. I will start implementing it right away. Thanks again for the great explanation.